# como puedo guardar datos desde un formulario html a una db mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

hola necesito saber como guardar datos a mi base de datos mysql usando php:

-**este es mi conexion**

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$db) or die ("no conecta al servidor local");

mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or die ("no conecta a la base de datos");

if ($con == TRUE) {
    echo "Conexion al host";

}

else{
    echo "no conecta";
}
```

?>

**y este es mi formulario***

```
<form method="post" action="php/registro.php">
            <label>Nombre</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required=""><br>
            <label>Apellido</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required=""><br>
            <label>Correo Electronico</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="correo@correo.correo" required=""><br>
            <label>Contraseña</label><br>

            +56 <input type="varchar" name="telefono" placeholder="" required=""><br>
            <label>Sexo</label><br>

            <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="hombre">Hombre<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="mujer">Mujer<br>
            <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="otro">Otro/a<br>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
            <input type="reset" name="" value="Borrar">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Lo que deberias hacer es lo siguiente

1. En ese archivo necesitas recibir tus variables por **POST** `$_POST['nombre']`
2. Luego deberias incluir la conexion a tu base de datos.
3. Realizar el **INSERT** a la tabla en tu BD

   `include 'conexion.php';
   //Recibes las variables por POST
   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
   $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
   //Haces lo demas con el  resto de los campos de tu formulario
   //Realizas el Insert a tu bd
   $sql="INSERT INTO tabla (nombre,apellido) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido')";
   //Ejecutas tu consulta y listo`